# Find diffrence between Orignal string and edited string in php?

Tags: php

I have the following 2 strings :

orignal string

```
$orignal_string="Hello world!";
```

edited string :

```
$edited_string="Hello Ladies!";
```

How can I find the diffrence between these two strings, and print the diffrence as **Ladies** for the given strings?

I am using strcmp() function, but it returns diffrence in numbric value.

```
 $orignal_string="Hello world!";
$edited_string="Hello Ladies!";
echo strp($orignal_string,$edited_string);
```

Is there any other way in php or regex to do this?

Comment: Did you give a look to https://github.com/sebastianbergmann/diff? It's the component at the core of PHPUnit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `explode` and `array_diff_assoc` (returns words that differ in this case) or `array_intersect_assoc` (returns words that are the same in this case) to find different words.

```
$original_string = "Hello world!";
$edited_string = "Hello Ladies!";

$orig = explode(" ", $original_string);
$edit = explode(" ", $edited_string);

$diff = array_diff_assoc($orig, $edit);
$intersect = array_intersect_assoc($orig, $edit);

echo "diff:\n";
print_r($diff);

echo "intersect:\n";
print_r($intersect);
```

Output:

```
diff:
Array
(
    [1] => world!
)
intersect:
Array
(
    [0] => Hello
)
```

Note that this only works on whole words. If new words are inserted or deleted in the edit string it'd screw the whole thing up though. This is not a fully fledged patchdiff-like approach.

For a unified diff of two string you might want to take a look at [xdiff_string_diff](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php).

Answer (score 1):

Here is what you are looking for [`xdiff_string_diff`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.xdiff-string-diff.php)

Note: This function doesn't work well with binary strings. To make diff of binary strings use `xdiff_string_bdiff()/xdiff_string_rabdiff()`.

Comment: This doesn't give you the difference though, which seems to be what OP is looking for. For simply checking if two strings are different there's already `strcmp`, which works faster than doing crc32 twice.